# How to decide on Xmx for heap size for a bulk ingestion project

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a bulk ingestion project for about 5 million documents (sized between 200KB-3MB each) to Alfresco using REST APIs and Spring Boot. My fat jar will runs like this in Dev and Test environment without any issues:

```
 java -Xms64m -Xmx1G -jar MyApplication.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config/jdbc.properties
```

For Prod environment, the server has 16GB available memory. How do I decide, on min and max heap size, given the size of each document (200KB - 3MB) and their volume as - 5 millions. I mean, what should be "sane" min max heap size?

```
java -Xms?? -Xmx?? -jar MyApplication.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config/jdbc.properties
```

**Vague question:** If I use `-Xms64m -Xmx1G` , does that mean at peak time (when the jvm is fully ramped up), my jvm will not process the documents batch size more than 1GB at any given time? Or in simple terms - where this 1GB will be burned in this situation? Or how JVM will utilize this 1GB?

Any relevant information/links in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Per Vishnu's comments, I found these (still trying to understand):
https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control/
https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-configure-stack-sizes
https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-stack-heap-definitions-memory/

And then I tried couple of ss parameters like below:

```
java -Xss1k -jar MyApplication.jar
```

results in:

```
The Java thread stack size specified is too small. Specify at least 136k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

And when I try this:

```
java -Xss136k -jar MyApplication.jar
```

I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.access$400(RandomAccessDataFile.java:205)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile.read(RandomAccessDataFile.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile.read(RandomAccessDataFile.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.load(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.fromRandomAccessData(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.doGetEntry(JarFileEntries.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.containsEntry(JarFileEntries.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.containsEntry(JarFile.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.get(JarURLConnection.java:263)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:83)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1074)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:643)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:314)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2473)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

> And it resulted in above SOF error from 136-240k but but worked on >
> 250k.

I know Vishnu's comments and this error is trying to indicate something which is going over my head. What is that? Can I get a simple (simpler or simplest will be better :P) answer here please?

Again I am trying to get a "sane" or "best" possible heap size for my application's jar.

Thanks a lot in advance to read such lengthy information and your kind help.

Comment: Why have you opted to you REST API, and not Bulk Import Tool, for instance?

Comment: There are bunch of things we are doing on-the-fly. Thats why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first decide on how many threads can run in parallel, the thread stack memory allocated using -Xss param. I think in 1.8 version on 64 bit each thread has a default memory of 1Mb.

Try using a Concurrent GC in Java Opts which will help reduce the heap.

Comment: Dude..you really made me scratching my head. However I added some more info. Please take a look and suggest with your expertise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the -Xss value of 1mb is fine to use. when you do start you app include the below command, this will help reduce your heap size.

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Since your host has a max of 16GB you can set you Max heap size to 4Gb,which will still give you some room to expand during peak if required.